# How to validate the uniqueness of attribute in two models in Rails?

Tags: ruby-on-rails

I have 2 models, University and Company, both of which have a name attribute. I am using the mailboxer gem so that both can act as messagable. My problem is that after I added auto-complete for the recipient of a message, I realized that the only value I have to find where I have to send the message is the name of the university or the company.

So now I am trying to enforce uniqueness of this attribute for both models. Is this possible and if yes, how?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You should use a custom validation, like:

company.rb

```
validates :name, uniqueness: true
validate :name_not_on_universities

private
def name_not_on_universities
    uname=University.where(:name => self.name).first
    uname.nil?
end
```

and similarly for the other model

Comment: I added this at the end of the method `unless uname.nil? errors.add(:name, "Already used") end`

Answer (score 0):

One way to do it is to use inheritance. You can have something like this:

Whatever.rb

```
Class Whatever < ActiveRecord::Base
....
validates :name, uniqueness: true
```

Company.rb

```
Class Company < Whatever
```

University.rb

```
Class University < Whatever
```