# Validating uniqueness of an attribute in two tables/models

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby-on-rails-4.2

I have two different kind of user (devise) models in my Rails application. Doctor and Patient. It was my fault I haven't defined an upper class User and inherit attributes from it. They have a mutual attribute - a personal identification number and I want two check uniqueness of this attribute in both of tables. I've searched a bit and saw [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/22455379/4481312).

I've applied things as it written there but it had no effect.

```
#patient.rb 
class Patient < ActiveRecord::Base

...
  validates_uniqueness_of :pin 
  validate :pin_not_on_doctors

  private

    def pin_not_on_doctors
        Doctor.where(:pin => self.pin).first.nil?
    end
end
#doctor.rb
class Doctor < ActiveRecord::Base

...
  validates_uniqueness_of :pin 
  validate :pin_not_on_patients

  private

    def pin_not_on_patients
        Patient.where(:pin => self.pin).first.nil?
    end
end
```

First I created a patient instance, then a doctor instance with the same pin I used in my first (patient) case. Rails unexpectedly didn't spit out an error message and created doctor instance, and more interestingly devise also turned a blind eye for duplicate email.

How can I overcome this problem?

Answer (score 2):

In addition to adding the error, try adding a line to return true/false,

Something like,

```
def pin_not_on_doctors
    errors.add :pin, "already exits" if Doctor.exists?(:pin => self.pin)
    Doctor.exists?(:pin => self.pin)
end
```

I don't know the details of your app, but in depending on how you're actually creating the object in this case, it might need that.

EDIT: Misread something in the original, looks like your current version is to just return true/false, so this probably doesn't help. Sorry.

Answer (score 1):

You should add the error on the validation function:
http://api.rubyonrails.org/classes/ActiveModel/Errors.html

```
def pin_not_on_doctors
    errors.add :pin, "already exists" if Doctor.exists?(:pin => self.pin)
end
```

Comment: Mate, I'm sorry for misunderstanding, my problem is not actually with error messages, but the way rails treated to me :) I expected that it will not create the doctor instance because of the duplicate pin. But it did create.

I'll now update the related part. 

P.S. Anyway, I checked your code, and the result is same. Maybe problem is somewhere else.

P.P.S. Anyway thanks for your attention :)

Comment: see the comment to your answer, you have to add error.